# Defining Bit-Flags Using #define in C++

Tags: c++, struct, c-preprocessor, bit, flags

I'm learning about bit-flags. I already know how they work and how they are defined in a `struct`. However, I'm unsure if they can be defined in a `#define` preprocessor directive like this:

```
#define FLAG_FAILED:1
```

Is this preprocessor define directive the as a `struct` bit-flag definition?

PS: I've already come across this related question but it didn't answer my question: [#defined bitflags and enums - peaceful coexistence in "c"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515086/defined-bitflags-and-enums-peaceful-coexistence-in-c). Also, if you can point me towards some information regarding preprocessor directives, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any #define that you want to use to inject bitflags into a struct must take the form:

```
#define IDENTIFIER SUBSTITUTED_CODE
```

In your postulated use...

```
#define FLAG_FAILED:1
```

The identifier contains the colon, which makes it invalid.

You could do something like this:

```
#define FLAG_FAILED int flag_failed :1

struct X
{
    char a;
    FLAG_FAILED;
    int b;
    ...
};
```

It's not clear why you're considering using a define for the bit field anyway.  If you just want to be able to vary the field length, then:

```
#define FLAG_FAILED_BITS 1

struct X
{
    unsigned flag_failed :FLAG_FAILED_BITS;
};
```

...or...

```
#define FLAG_FAILED_BITS :1

struct X
{
    unsigned flag_failed FLAG_FAILED_BITS;
};
```

Comment: Simply put. Why can't all questions be answered like this? Thank you, Tony.

Answer (score 1):

`#define FLAG_FAILED:1` is not really a bit flag in the sense that what most people know as a "bit flag". It's also bad syntax.

Bit flags typically are defined so that you have a *type* and you turn "on" bits by "setting" them. You turn them "off" by "clearing" the flag. To compare if the bit flag is on, you use what is called the *bitwise* operator `AND` (e.g. **&**).

So your BIT0 (e.g. 2^0) would be *defined* as `BIT0 = 0x00000001` and BIT1 (e.g. 2^1) as `BIT1 = 0x00000002`. If you wanted to stick with *define* you could do it this way with setting and clearing:

```
#ifndef setBit
#define setBit(word, mask) word |= mask
#endif

#ifndef clrBit
#define clrBit(word, mask) word &= ~mask
#endif
```

or as a template

```
template<typename T>
inline T& setBit(T& word, T mask) { return word |= mask; }

template<typename T>
inline T& clrBit(T& word, T mask) { return word &= ~mask; }
```

If you want to set the bit, so to speak, you could have a state set as follows:

`setBit(SystemState, SYSTEM_ONLINE);`

or

`setBit(SystemState, <insert type here>SYSTEM_ONLINE);`

clearing would be the same just replace `setBit` with `clrBit`.

To compare, just do this:

```
if (SystemState & SYSTEM_ONLINE) { ... // do some processing 

}
```

if this is in a `struct` then, reference the `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

A form to define bitwise values with #define macros is:

```
#define BIT_ONE    static_cast<int>( 1 << 0 )
#define BIT_TWO    static_cast<int>( 1 << 1 )
#define BIT_THREE  static_cast<int>( 1 << 2 )
```